# Significance of $(l+m)!$ in the standard formula for combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I have understood that in dividing $N$ distinct objects into $2$ groups containing $p$ and $q$ objects respectively (where $N = p + q$), number of combinations can be given by
$$\frac{N!}{p!q!}$$
when $p\neq q$. I understand $N!$ accounts for the total number of arrangements and division by $p!$ and $q!$ prevents overcounting of arrangements within the respective groups. However, when the group sizes are the same i.e. $p= q=r$, we must divide by $2!$ to not overcount for arrangements of groups that are the same. So, it becomes
$$\frac{N!}{(r!)^2 2!}$$
The book I follow says that in general, the number of ways of dividing $N$ distinct objects into $l$ groups containing $p$ objects each and $m$ groups containing $q$ objects each is equal to
$$\frac{N!(l+m)!}{(p!)^l (q!)^m l!m!}$$
Here $N=lp+mq$.
I know $(p!)^l$ and $(q!)^m$ prevents overcounting of arrangements within the respective groups, and $l!m!$ prevents overcounting of arrangements of the same-size groups. But I don't understand what factor $(l+m)!$ is for. Doesn't it overcount for arrangements of $(l+m)$ groups already accounted for in $N!$ ?

Comment: Wecome to Mathematics StackExchange! Not only do I not know what the $(l+m)!$ does, but also its presence seems to contradict the previous formulas. If $l$ and $m$ are both $1$, then we should get back to the first formula, but there is an extra factor of $2!$ in the numerator instead. And if $l$ is $2$ while $m$ is $0$, then we should recover the second formula, but again there's an extra factor of $2!$ in the numerator. Are you sure that the formula with $(l+m)!$ is for the situation that you're describing, and are you sure that you're describing it correctly?

Comment: @TobyBartels I have rechecked that the book (more specifically a JEE coaching module) I follow gives this formula. And the formula does seem to contradict the previous ones because of including $(l+m)!$. And though I have never found a solution using this, I thought the $(l+m)!$ might have an explanation. Perhaps it's a gross mistake in the book?

Comment: From what you describe, it seems to be a mistake; these do happen sometimes! Besides comparing the other formulas, we can also do a check with some small numbers, say $p=1$, $q=2$, $l=2$, $m=2$, so $N=6$. I listed them all, and while this comment is too short to write them out, I got $45$ of them, not $1080$. (Unfortunately, the number quickly gets too large to handle much beyond this example.)

Comment: I have thought of a possible meaning for the extra factor in a different situation. If, after splitting the $N$ items into $l$ groups of size $p$ and $m$ groups of size $q$, making $l+m$ groups altogether, you were then to take these groups and put them in order, then the formula in the coaching module would tell you how many ways to do that.

Comment: @TobyBartels That should make sense, though all the module specifies is >In general, the number of ways of dividing $n$ distinct objects into $l$ groups containing $p$ objects each and $m$ groups containing $q$ objects each is equal to 
$$\frac{n!(l+m)!}{(p!)^l (q!)^m l!m!}$$
Here $lp+mq=n$

Comment: Many thanks! @TobyBartels

Comment: You're welcome!